crashing the app in c# socket programming
I wrote this code in C# winforms but it crashes in line 33 and it will be freezed and not responding.
I put all the code in the button click so that when I click the button the server runs and the client could connect to that.
I would be happy if you solve this with your solution.
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

namespace Server_SP
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Socket listenerr = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            IPAddress localAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
            IPEndPoint localEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(localAddress, 8575);
            listenerr.Bind(localEndpoint);

            IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("0.0.0.0");
            int port = 8575;
            TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(ipAddress, port);
            listener.Start();
            label2.Text = "Serving on Port 8587";
            while (true)
            {
                label1.Text = " Waiting for connection...";
                TcpClient cliend = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                label1.Text = "Client Accepted";
                NetworkStream stream = cliend.GetStream();
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(cliend.GetStream());
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(cliend.GetStream());
                try
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    int count = 0;
                    //////how many bytes
                    foreach (byte b in buffer)
                    {
                        if (b!=0)
                        {
                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                    string reced = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, count);
                    label3.Text = "Request Reced: " + reced;
                    sw.WriteLine("Hiiii.I am serverrr");
                    sw.Flush();
                }
                catch (Exception errorr)
                {
                    label1.Text = "Errorrrr";
                    sw.WriteLine(errorr.ToString());

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

I removed the while loop and also replaced the line 41 whith the code below but didnt help.
TcpClient cliend = listenerr.AcceptTcpClient(); 

Actually I did this job in console properly and it works, but when I tried to port that code to a windows application I faced these issues.

You don't do yourself any services by having variable names listener and listenerr. Meaningful variable names would help.

Also, which line is 41? To me it looks like a }.

Likewise, performing blocking operations in a UI thread, in a loop which never terminates, with exception "handling" which just catches the exception and continues, doesn't sound like a great plan.

I doubt that we can solve it here, to your and our satisfaction. The entire concept needs a redesign unfortunately. And this would go beyond the scope of your question. Please rather invest a little more time in researching a tutorial on how to implement a server client connection that runs in the background

What is the actual goal? If you just want to send data between computers I would highly recommend using an existing protocol and library, like Http, gRPC, or MQTT. This should be far easier to use. Writing network code yourself is somewhat difficult, and you need to be familiar with concepts like threading, message framing and error handling for all the different ways things can go wrong.

It seems you need to move the server code to a separate thread to avoid blocking the UI like this
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run(()=>HandleServer());
}
    
private void HandleServer()
{
    // do your stuff run the server and also the while loop
}


Moving the server to a background thread is required, but not sufficient. This will just cause the program to crash when the label is updated on a background thread. There are also several other issues that need to be dealt with for reliable communication.

You have fallen into the trap that you expect TCP to work in 'packets', whereas it works in 'streams'.
You told the stream to read 1024 bytes, and not return until they have all turned up, which is why you believe it's locked up.
TCP requires an application protocol of some sort.  Generally, the protocol would start with some sort of header that contains the length of the data, but could also work with a terminator (like CR/LF).  In your case, you could just keep reading one byte at a time until you receive '\n'.  The issue with this, is that if the sender never sends a terminator, your UI will block forever.
